# Set a Java Security Property to null

Tags: java, security, properties

I have seen that one can null (or clear) a System property by using `System.clearProperty("propertyName")`.  However, I am unable to locate a similar mechanism for Security.

How does one perform the equivalent of `Security.clearProperty("propertyName")`?

Obviously, using `Security.setProperty("propertyName", null)` does not work for the same reasons it does not work for `System.setProperty("propertyName", null)`.

I would like to do this as there are optional security properties that may not be updated when required properties are changed.  I would like the optional properties to reset to their default values when a change is made to the required properties.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies having re-looked into this I believe

```
System.clearProperty
```

will not work for **security** properties. I'm not sure how to do it programmatically however you can create a new security policy file with your required settings within it and use that:

```
Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/path/to/new/policy_file
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I see the mistake I made in my post and have updated it.  AFAIK, the -D options are at JVM start.  I need to modify the value during program execution.  Please correct me if I am wrong.  I started looking into modifying the Policy on the fly and will continue to do so.

Comment: After spending some time with Policy, it doesn't appear that it is viable for me due to other implementation constraints.